# Затруднение при постановке запятой в переводе

Tags: пунктуация

Затруднение при постановке запятой в переводе:
...Юпитер поравнялся с марсом() и теперь(,) я и моя тачка непобедимы...

Смело тычьте в правила.

Comment: @freelanSER, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Юпитер поравнялся с Марсом, и теперь я и моя тачка непобедимы... Запятая разделяет две части сложносочиненного предложения. После "теперь" запятая не нужна, так как для этого нет никаких причин, ибо это просто один из членов предложения

Comment: Спасибо, ибо ясно...

Comment: Можете принять ответ.